# fastest way to check if atleast one element in set/list is in each element in a collection of lists/sets

Tags: python, performance

I have the following:

```
list1 = {"a", "b", "c"}

list2 = [
    {"a", "s", "d", "f"},
    {"q", "w", "e", "c"},
    {"v", "b", "n", "m"},
]
```

i now want to check that elements in list1 are somewhere in list2. each element in list2 MUST contain one of the elements in list1.

what i currently do is the following (also found it on stackoverflow a while ago):

```
all(list1 & l for l in list2)
```

this is actually reasonably fast. however I am now running into the issue that I have billions of different list1, so I have to come up with a faster solution. I also tried numba, but I am struggling with nested lists, and sets are not supported.

I have a bunch of items (like the sets in list2) that can represent that sets. for example, the first set in list2 consists of "a", "s", "d" and "f". all of those characters "desribe" the first set in list2.

what I now want to do is find the shortest combination to describe list2. for example:

```
list2 = [
    {"a", "s", "d", "f"},
    {"q", "w", "e", "c"},
    {"v", "b", "n", "m"},
    {"v", "l", "p", "o"},
]
```

here the shortest combination to describe list2 is a,q,v (a describes the first element, q the second and v elements 3 and 4)

the way i construct list1 would be to take

```
U = set.union(*list2)

for list1 in itertools.combinations(U,3): #i loop over the combinations to find the minimum one, so combinations(U,2), combinations(U,3) ....
     ...
```

this works really well, even for very large numbers (100s of millions of combinations), however it is still somewhat limited. I would like to reduce it as much as I can.
edit: the datastructure for list2 is as desribed above, a collection of sets containing strings (in my case its 3 character combinations), and so list1 is also a set of strings.

thanks

Comment: Divide your data in sections and go full parallel

Comment: "I have billions of different list1," What should your result look like? Do you need to figure out a separate answer for each of the `list1`s? Or do you want to know whether any of the elements of any of the `list1`s meets the condition? Or something else? And why do you actually have this much data, and a need to compute this result? What is the underlying *problem that you hope to solve* by this computation?

Comment: Not sure how "fastest" can be anything but a subjective answer.  As stated, performance, depends on the environment.  How much data do you have (elements in set, number of sets)?  How are you generating the data?  Could you generate sorted tuple instead? Do you need to this repeatedly?  If you want to go fast, why are you using Python which is probably 10x slower than C/C++ etc.  What CPU are you using?  How many cores?  Do you have GPUs do you have available?  Do you want to run this on a cluster?  Say, 1 node per set, would be linear time.

Comment: The main problem with Numba looks to be the datatype (sets are supported, but it looks there is some problem with unicode letters). Can you represent this letters as simple uint8 number?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple optimization you can make,

```
not any(map(list1.isdisjoint, list2))
```

`isdisjoint` avoids needing to calculate the full result, and `map` is faster than a comprehension when you are just calling a single method.

However, if you want a more optimal result you have to give more detail about what you are trying to do. Particularly, what are the sizes of all of the data structures, and what are the elements they contain?

Comment: hey thanks for that suggestion, it is almost twice as fast as my solution! i will update my original post with that i am trying to achive, i dont have the characters here.

Answer (score 1):

> what I now want to do is find the shortest combination to describe list2

This is the [Hitting Set Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation), which is well studied and for which there exist multiple solvers, [like this one](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/examples/hitman.html).

Comment: hey thank you so much for your help. this module looks very interesting. i noticed that sometimes it would return solutions where a set in list2 would be described twice( e.g. "a" and "f" are in the solutions, however i can solve that by just checking the length of the final solution. thanks again and happy easter